# How to apply css type styling for each individual View in Home Controller

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

Because I am somewhat a beginner in ASP.Net, I cannot figure out how to give each individual View its own style. I have gotten the main Index() View its own background and colours within the _Layout.cshtml, but I cannot seem to give any other of the the Views their own styles.

I've only tried applying styles to the About.cshtml file, and I have also tried referencing an external CSS style sheet.

Within the _Layout.cshtml file right after the `<head>`:

```
<body class="body-content" runat="server" style="background-image: url('images/MovieReel.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
```

and so on.

Within the **About.cshtml** View:

```
<body style="background-image: url('images/MovieReel.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

Basically, I want a static background for the entire asp.net web page, but I can only get the background to show on the Index View (or the Home page). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Well, may be it doesn't work because your About page would render duplicate body Html tag. If the layout includes Hrml `body` tag and there's a `@RenderBody()` inside that, then the code produced by the view will end up there. Just create new project from scratch with Visual Studio template and try to understand how it works.

Comment: You should only but the <body> tag inside `_Layout.cshtml` page then apply the `Layout` to the AboutUs page to use it `@{Layout =" ~/View/_Layout.cshtml"}`